# Tons of Processes Running

Tags: 13.04, ram, process

I have an Ubuntu 13.04 running on a P4 computer with 1 Gb of RAM (I know, I need to get a new one). I recently have been getting crashes, and a lot of my memory is being used. So I looked in Top and there's literally hundreds of the same processes running. Some are Apache, Postdrop, and Sendmail. They're hogging my RAM! How do I stop them? Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What are you using this computer for?? Apache is a webserver, postdrop a SQL thing and sendmail is a mail server type thing..

Comment: Could you paste the output of `top` or of `ps ax`? It would help too see what processes you might don't need. What is the purpose of this computer? Do you use it as server or SOHO machine?

Answer (score 0):

1st, take a look at [Linux Ate my RAM](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) to understand how memory management is done by Linux kernel.

2nd, remove all server packages that you don't need, .e.g. `apache2`, `mysql`, `sendmail` etc...

Paste your `pstree` output so that we can help you to figure out what you don't need.

Comment: Okay. Will have a look at your link, and post that data as soon as the machine boots up. Oh, and this IS a server, so I need Apache, MySQL, etc.

Comment: And it just crashed a few minutes ago stating it couldn't allocate memory.

Comment: The server simply does NOT have enough RAM to run the services.

Comment: It has worked for a long time with no problems, but then about a month ago this started to happen.